# AtomicMarkableReference with multiple booleans

Tags: java, data-structures, concurrency, atomic

I am looking to find a class in Java which allows me to implement an atomic object with 3 mark bits instead of one. AtomicMarkableReference serves the purpose if I just needed 1 mark bit, but is there any way to implement an atomic reference with 3 mark bits instead of 1 or is there any class which does this?

Comment: Well, you can always take the source code of `AtomicMarkableReference` and replace the boolean with an `int`. It won't be very portable though as the original implementation uses `sun.misc.Unsafe`

Comment: Why do you need to use just 3 bits? Can you not use an AtomicStampedReference as the memory you save could be notional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you want [AtomicStampedReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicStampedReference.html) which stores up to 32-bits with each reference